# interpret crash report iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, crash-reports

my iPad app was working fine, I left it in the field for testing, but now is crashing[when saving?]

this is the crash log,

```
Incident Identifier: 80FC6810-9604-4EBA-A982-2009AB4C499A
CrashReporter Key:   70f90f207f55189d97c273c94d2659ad422909e2
Hardware Model:      iPad1,1
Process:         StaffManager [902]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/133747B7-0CB2-48FB-8A17-CE6AFB08DD22   /StaffManager.app/StaffManager
Identifier:      StaffManager
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-07-12 10:02:56.519 +1000
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.3.2 (8H7)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00000009
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x35c98c98 0x35c96000 + 11416
1   StaffManager                    0x00008d32 0x1000 + 32050
```

found this, 
EXC_BAD_ACCESS/KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE ? This is caused by the thread trying to write to read-only memory. This is always caused by a data access.

and that the problem is in

> libobjc.A.dylib

but what is the meaning of that? and how to fix it?, oh and why was it working before and now is not?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually assume EXC_BAD_ACCESS to mean that you are doing something with an object that has a zero retain count. From your report I would assume that as you say it's libobjc.dynlib that is triggering the error, but seeing as this appears to be the object C runtime, I'd look bck up the stack and at the *StaffManager* manager class.

This is just a guess :-)